# Turbolinks 5, jQuery 3: anyway to avoid event.off(...).on(...) for duplicate events?

Tags: jquery, performance, coffeescript, turbolinks

I'm building a Rails 4 application with Turbolinks 5 and jQuery 3.

On my main `global.coffee` where I do my app loading, I use a CoffeeScript class to abstract some of the event handling:

```
# app/javascripts/global.coffee
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  App.MD.ExpansionPanel.init()

# app/javascripts/expansion_panel.coffee
class App.MD.ExpansionPanel
  @init: () ->
    $(document).off("click", "[data-behavior='expansion-panel-toggle']").on "click", "[data-behavior='expansion-panel-toggle']", (e) ->
      $panel = $(this).closest("[data-behavior='expansion-panel']")
      $details = $panel.find("[data-behavior='expansion-panel-details']")

      if $panel.attr("data-state") == "expanded"
        $panel.attr("data-state", "collapsed")
      else
        $panel.attr("data-state", "expanded")

# Some sample HTML (clicking any toggle element toggles between the summary or detail view)
<div data-behavior="expansion-panel">
  <div data-behavior="expansion-panel-summary">
    <div data-behavior="expansion-panel-toggle">Summary Toggle</div>
  </div>
  <div data-behavior="expansion-panel-details">
    <div data-behavior="expansion-panel-toggle">Details Toggle</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that the events were firing multiple times and my expand/collapse panels would toggle both events, thus returning the panel to the original state.

I fixed this by using `.off("click", ...).on("click", ...)` to first remove the `click` event and then re-add it, but something tells me this isn't very performant or a great solution, since I've never had to do this before.

**Is there a more performant way to setup this event handler?**

I have dynamic content added via AJAX, which is why I added the event to the `document` itself and not some parent context.

Comment: Why does it have to be setup on `turbolinks:load` anyway? Wouldn't `ready` be sufficient? It's a delegated event handler so registering it once on page load means it will keep on working for even dynamic content.

Comment: When you use Turbolinks, it no longer fires the DOM `ready` event and instead fires the `turbolinks:load` event to mimic page loads. Turbolinks gives you some feeling of a single-page app but the trade-off is using different events to initiate JavaScript.

Comment: I understand the turbolinks part - but the `ready` event still fires, but only on page load. There is no need to remove and reattach the event on every `turbolinks:load`. The event handler should still work if only attached once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `$(document).on('click','.selector', function(){...})` should be declared **outside** of `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(event) {..});`.

This lead me to the solution: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-turbolinks/2.1.0#Events_firing_twice_or_more

And the current docs say something similar:

> When possible, avoid using the turbolinks:load event to add other
>   event listeners directly to elements on the page body. Instead,
>   consider using event delegation to register event listeners once on
>   document or window.
>   -- https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events

I had a similar case (an off-canvas menu), that only worked with unbinding (`*.off()`) the event first. Now with binding the event outside of `turbolinks:load`, it works as expected.